# is there an method to remove first occurence using lambda function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have the following plist as created below one.

plist=['D', 'o', 'n', 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c']

Now the task to be accomplished is remove the charecters p,a,n,D and append it to plist. But one condition here is that if there are two n's only the first occurence should be removed.

I have tried using the lambda functions to remove them but unable to remove only the first occurence of n .

Lambda function: lst=list(filter(lambda x:x.lower() not in['o','t',"'",'i','c',' '],plist))

can someone help me with some ideas of how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

## DELETE FIRST OCCURRENCE OF AN ELEMENT

If you have to use lambda (it would be easier without it).
You can try returning this in lambda:

```py
lambda l,e: [x for i,x in enumerate(l) if i!= (l+[e]).index(e)]
```

> In the example of above you return the element if its index is not the same of the first occurrence in the list. In the comprobation of the index, you should concat the element at the end to avoid an exception. If the concatenated element is the first occurrence the index is bigger that every index in the list so you returns all the elements.

If you don't use lambda:

```py
def remove_first_occurrence(l,element):
    if element in l:
        l.remove(element) # removes the first occurence
    return l
```

## DELETE FIRST OCCURRENCE OF MULTIPLE ELEMENTS

And if you want to delete the first occurrence of a list of elements:

```py
def remove_first_occurrence_of_multiple_elements(l, elements):
    for element in elements:
        if element in l:
            l.remove(element)  # removes the first occurence
    return l


plist = ['D', 'o', 'n', 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c']
elements_to_remove = ['o', 't', "'", 'i', 'c', ' ']
new_plist = remove_first_occurrence_of_multiple_elements(plist,elements_to_remove)
print(new_plist)
```

## IMPORTANT

> In this examples it's diferrent "o" of "O"

I hope it helps

Comment: what is the use of enumerate ?

Comment: Enumerate method returns list of tuples. Each element of this list has to elements inside (index , value). So you have the position of an element and the element